# will "TelephonyManager.getLine1Number()" return "0000000000" in any case?

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I am using the device number to create a account in one of our server. The following code I am using to get the device number,

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String phoneNumber = telephonyManager.getLine1Number();
```

But our server people are complaining that some accounts are registering with "0000000000" number.

is there any possibility that the above code will return such weird number ?

I saw this number is hard coded in `ConnectivityService.java` of android source code.

```
com.android.server.ConnectivityService#getMobileProvisioningUrl
```

is it somehow connected with this `Service` class ?

Comment: You cannot always get the phone number. Some telecom providers do not give out this information in the SIM card and hence you cannot read it.

Comment: A better way to get the phone number is to let the user enter it, and verify it using SMS.

Comment: Yeah but in that case it will retun null , not such weird number